# How to Post a List in Django Tests

Tags: python, django, list, testing, post

I have a view which AJAX posts to with a list of items. I am attempting to add a test for this.

How can I post a list in a django test? I retrieve the data through this command:

```
listVar = request.POST.getlist('list[]')
```

I know this receives a list properly because I interface with Jquery and it returns the proper list, but how can I do this is python?
I have been trying code like this however printing 'listVar' always yields an empty list:

```
form = {"list": ["element 1", "element 2"]}
response = self.client.post('/viewurl/', form, follow=True)
```

Edit---
@Tomek suggested to drop the '[]', however that causes the python post request to work, but my ajax upload to return an empty list.

Here is a snippet of my ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
        url: window.location.pathname,
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            list: a_list_I_create_elsewhere
        },
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just drop the`[]` in the `getlist` argument.

```
def request_handler(request):
    listVar = request.POST.getlist('list')
    print(listVar)
```

should work

EDIT
Not to break compatibility with jQuery. I guess I'd test according to jQuery format

```
form = {"list[]": ["element 1", "element 2"]}
response = self.client.post('/viewurl/', form, follow=True)
```

Comment: sorry I didn't clarify well enough, this would break my AJAX upload, which is the main purpose of the view

Comment: yeah, I just noticed the change.. I think I'd consider changing the unit test in your case

Comment: Oh, I see, because the [] is added automatically in AJAX. Thank you